# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting an error on line 1 of this code...

```
Select COUNT(MEM_REL) As MemberSub, CLM_CC2 As GroupNum
From Impact.dbo.tbl_mem, Impact.dbo.tbl_clm 
Where MEM_REL = '01'
Group by CLM_CC2
```

The error is:

```
MSg 8815, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int
```

Comment: becuase you are passing `MEM_REL = '01'` you have to pass `MEM_REL = 1`

Comment: You are missing a `JOIN` in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: Where am I putting the join @GordonLinoff?

Comment: @tinka that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You really should not use a comma separated list of tables. It works but it it a very old join style. You should be explicit and state that you want a CROSS JOIN. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you show us the error code and any backtrace information it gives you?

Comment: @AJFaraday 'MSg 8815, Level 16, State 2, Line 1' 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int'.

Comment: @AnalystSupreme -Can you add schema and sample data of yourtable. I dont see any the possibility to get this error

Comment: When I get rid of 'CLM_CC2 As GroupNum', 'Impact.dbo.tbl_clm' and change the Group by to 'MEM_REL', everything works fine. It seems like it does not want to convert when I have them both in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try introducing a proper relation to the query, right now you are getting a Cartesian product of the two tables. For example instead of the comma `,` use the key word `JOIN` to join two tables and then define the relation on what column you want to join these tables.

Once you have done the above the number of rows returned will dramatically decrease and the following query may work, if you have more than 2.2 billion rows in the following query then you may need to use `COUNT_BIG()` function instead of just `COUNT()`

```
Select COUNT(MEM_REL) As MemberSub
     , CLM_CC2 As GroupNum
From Impact.dbo.tbl_mem
INNER JOIN Impact.dbo.tbl_clm 
ON dbo.tbl_mem.[ReferencingColumn] = dbo.tbl_clm.[ReferencingColumn]
Where MEM_REL = '01'
Group by CLM_CC2
```

Query with COUNT_BIG()

```
Select COUNT_BIG(MEM_REL) As MemberSub
     , CLM_CC2 As GroupNum
From Impact.dbo.tbl_mem
INNER JOIN Impact.dbo.tbl_clm 
ON dbo.tbl_mem.[ReferencingColumn] = dbo.tbl_clm.[ReferencingColumn]
Where MEM_REL = '01'
Group by CLM_CC2
```